# Why is the clip art image distorted in Asset Studio?

Tags: android-studio, assets, android-resources, android-asset-studio

I don't really understand why this is the case, but for some reason it is not possible to add resources with asset studio without them being in this weird shape:

[image of issue in Asset Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO3sv.png)

Am I missing the point, I cannot really see an intention in this, shouldn't you be able to add resources exactly as the developer designed them?

Additionally I would like to use googles stock clip art, however this wont allow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the new "Layout Rendering Engine" in Android Studio.

Disable using the following: `Settings` -> `Experimental` -> `Use new Layout Rendering Engine`